# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5

I'm completly stuck on this. I keep getting error message

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I'm using pycharm with pyqt5.6 and qt5.6.2 and the problem started when I upgraded to these versions.

I've tried searching as much as I can, but have not been able to find an answer. Can anyone help please?

Comment: that's the code for null pointer exception.

Comment: @ARob4. Exit codes are completely useless for debugging. Please learn how to configure your programming environment so that it displays the python traceback. Or run the code in a console or command window instead of IDE so you can see the output directly.

Comment: @ekhumoro The Python interpreter is crashing with non-zero exit code when PyCharm/IntelliJ attempts to iterate properties.  In this scenario, the Python interpreter does not provide an exception stack trace.  It is possible that Linux could provide a `core` dump.

Comment: Encountered this in some legacy unittests due to multiple `QtWidgets.QApplication` instances. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/74303807

Answer (score 17):

Assume you are running under Windows. Application Error code 0xc0000005, also known as Access Violation error, is a common problem experienced by Windows users, regardless of os version. There are various causes to trigger Application Error 0xc0000005. For my case, I'm running debug mode in PyCharm (or Eclipse) with code that includes the following:

```
from pympler import muppy
all_objects=muppy.get_objects()  # this causes pydev debugger exit with code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

It was perfectly fine if execute the same piece of code through PyCharm in non-debug (Run) mode. Disabled the above code in debug mode, issue resolved.

Environment: PyCharm Community 2019.3, Anaconda 3, Python 3.7.3, pympler 0.7, Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: This was helpful, although not exactly what happened to me. I was getting the error both in 'debug' & 'run' mode in PyCharm, but it was definitely PyCharm that was causing the error. I ran the script from terminal and the error was gone.

Comment: Found it helps that `PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL=NO` in Debug Configurations. via. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-48739/starting-the-debugger-gives-exit-code-1073741819-0xC0000005#focus=Comments-27-4886321.0-0

Comment: @Weekend thanks, this solved my problem on IntelliJ Enterprise with Python plugin.

Answer (score 9):

Use `faulthandler` it will show the stack trace when application crashes through which u can debug the issue

```
import faulthandler

if __name__ == "__main__":

    faulthandler.enable() #start @ the beginning

    ... # application logic
```

Answer (score 7):

While developing SQLAlchemy application I run into the same issue.

I've added the `-X dev` (https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#miscellaneous-options) ***Interpreter options* in PyCharm Run/Debug Configurations** which resulted in new exceptions instead of crashing with -1073741819 (0xc0000005). These exceptions did not appear before.

Comment: Didn't solve my problem but it is nice to debug, thank you

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this error, and found it was caused by using a method from a newer version of Python than my venv was configured (match/case in 3.10.0 with 3.8 as the interpreter)

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is the *'right'* way to do it but I ended up completely uninstalling anaconda and rebuilding it. When I then made a new virtual environment the problem resolved. If others have the same issue this might work too. By the way the problem first occurred with an update to pyqt5.

Comment: Do you remember what solved your problem? I get the same error codes and I'm using PySide2 (now the official Python bindings for Qt 5).

Comment: Yes, it wasn't anything to do my the code, it was due to problems finding the DLLs that were needed. The path environment variable wasn't pointing to the right place. Trial and error was all that worked!

Comment: Okay. I had a completely weird problem, where if I assigned the pixmap from a `QImage` to a `QLabel`, with `setPixmap`, in the same function as I created the `QImage`, it would work fine, whereas if I created the `QImage` in one function, stored it, and then assigned its pixmap to the `QLabel` in another function, the script would crash and give me this error code during the call to `setPixmap`. I have no idea why this happened, but I simply made sure to have the `QImage` creation and the call to `setPixmap` in the same function because then it works.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem,  this resolved in my case:

- try run from command line (no pycharm), it works ( exception only in debug )
- closed pycharm
- deleted ".idea" folder inside project path
- opened pycharm
- reconfigure python runtime version and command line parameter
- debug works

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem solve it by updating my tensorflow. There is probably some kind of compatibility problem. I realize the problem was from my "import tensorflow" because i was not getting an obvious error right after the import line.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue today.  I found this question while Googling for an answer!  By luck, I found the root cause in my code.

When I tried to expand a `self` pointer in the IntelliJ Python debugger, my Python interpreter would crash with: `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

Here is the code that caused the issue:

```
@property
def prop(self):
    return self.prop  # Facepalm: I meant to write: self._prop
```

When expanding `self` in the debugger, IntelliJ iterates all properties in the object.  If there is infinite loop/recursion, the Python interpreter will crash.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today when plotting a simple matrix. For me just changing the Python interpreter helped. I am not sure why, but I could imagine it has something to do with the installed libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally get this error when I use the boolean operation methods provided by the [PyVista](https://docs.pyvista.org/version/stable/examples/01-filter/boolean-operations.html) library. So, as far as I am concerned, this is not due to PyCharm but to PyVista (i.e. VTK) only (running the code from a terminal does not change the outcome).

As noted in this PyVista [issue](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/issues/1120#issuecomment-769415316):

> Boolean operations within VTK are prone to error [...].

Cleaning the mesh can prevent the occurrence of this error.

Answer (score -1):

I also had that issue. I worked on a big project and completely changed a significant part of it for better UX. Then this error occurred, and it was because I changed two lines in the .config file to make it easier to read.

So, check EVERY CHANGE since the last working commit.