# Python Google spreadsheets

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
Hi! I have a list of names that has about maybe 16000 names inside it.
items = [[Name]]
print(items)
service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range="Sheet1!A:A",
valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS", body={"values": items}).execute()

My task is to upload the 16000 items into a google spreadsheet. It works perfectly fine..
However, it doesnt upload all the names and throughout the process after about 40th item, it gives me this error:Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
Please, i have been trying to figure this out for hours... Created a new spreadsheet, did the same thing as before and it still gives me an error.
I was wondering if my problem was that i am trying to put all these items into the spreadsheet at one time.
If this is the real root of the problem, please could somebody give me a solution of how to only upload, eg 10 names at one time so this error does not happen?
Please help.

Comment: What is the platform you are using?

Comment: @hpchavaz pycharm.. however.. i have tried putting the code to linux and it gives a segmentation fault. (core dumped)

Comment: May be give  a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50620954/process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741819-0xc0000005-pycharm

Comment: @hpchavaz. I have tried it, however, it doesnt really solve the issue..