# How to write unit tests for a pyqt5 QApplication?

Tags: qt, unit-testing, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm trying to make some unit tests for a pyqt5 application. The problem is that I cannot run multiple tests in a test suite because I'm not clearning up the application properly and the end of every test.

```
class MainWindowTest(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, widgetTypeUnderTest=None, model=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.widgetTypeUnderTest = widgetTypeUnderTest
        self.model = model

        # setting title
        self.setWindowTitle("AccosTest")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 600)

        self.mainWindowLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        # container widget for everything else
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.mainWindowLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.show()


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.app.exit()

    def test(self):
        mainWindow = MainWindowTest()

    def test2(self):
        mainWindow = MainWindowTest()
```

Runing `Tests.test1` or `Tests.test2` individually does what is required, although this is likely because a second `QApplication` has not been started. When running both tests together I get a segfault.

Would anybody know the correct commands to properly dismantle the `QApplication` after every test, since `self.app.exit()` doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Thanks!

## edit

Do you think a better strategy would be to have two threads. One would start the main loop `sys.exit(self.app.exec())` and the other would wait for a while and then call exit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is normally no need to recreate a QApplication, even for testing (unless you *do* need to make multiple tests for the behavior of the program when the application is started or quit).

You can get the current existing QApplication using [`instance()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#instance):

```
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.app = QApplication.instance() or QApplication.(sys.argv)
```

In the rare case for which you really need to restart the application, then you need to ensure that the previous application has *really* been quit. Since that presumes the fact that `exec()` has been called, you can then destroy the `app` reference and recreate it again.

Note that you cannot create another application outside of the main thread (or, to be precise, outside the thread in which the first application was created).

Comment: This has been exceptionally useful, Thanks. I've looked everywhere for a good way to test QApplications in pyqt5 and it seems one way is to share the same QApplication and another is to call `del self.app`. I will post the working code as an answer for people that follow.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @musicamante for the answer.

Here it is in code:

## Option 1

Use the destructor, using `del` in python.

```
class MainWindowTest(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, widgetTypeUnderTest=None, model=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.widgetTypeUnderTest = widgetTypeUnderTest
        self.model = model

        # setting title
        self.setWindowTitle("AccosTest")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 600)

        self.mainWindowLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        # container widget for everything else
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.mainWindowLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.show()


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        del self.app

    def test(self):
        mainWindow = MainWindowTest()

    def test2(self):
        mainWindow = MainWindowTest()
```

## Option 2

Make `QApplication` global and

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.app = app.instance()

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.app.closeAllWindows()

    def test(self):
        mainWindow = MainWindowTest()

    def test2(self):
        mainWindow = MainWindowTest()
```

It seems that `Option 2` should be preferred because you shouldn't need to make and destroy the `QApplication` after every test. However, my personal preference is `Option 1` to keep unit tests completely independent.