# Azure function Blob Trigger being thrown "Language Worker Process exited. Pid=1652. python exited with code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)."

Tags: python, pandas, azure, sqlalchemy, azure-functions

I have a Blob Trigger function running that takes xml files and ends up storing the data into an Azure SQL db. Mainly through the use of pandas and SQL Alchemy. I have had no real other problem with any other xml file, but this specific one being ran through sends me an error:

> Language Worker Process exited. Pid=1652.
> python exited with code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

This error seems to trigger when data is being inserted into a specific table. This error doesn't mean much to me, what are possible issues that could be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

> Language Worker Process exited. Pid=1652. python exited with code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

This error could be because of many reasons like issues with the code or the dependencies you are using or the configuration.

***Need to check below:***

- Make sure you are using valid version of python.
- Check if the XML file you are trying to process is corrupted or contains unexpected/invalid data that is causing the crash.
- Since you mentioned there was no issue with the other xml files when processed, check the data of your current file to make sure it is valid XML file and can be parsed by your code.
- Also, you can try inserting the data manually of your xml file into the table and check if the error persists.
- Check all the required dependencies are installed and make sure there are no compatibility issues between the different versions of packages.
- Try to upload any other xml file and check if it is leading to the same error.
- This error ( 0xc0000005) also refers to ***Access or memory Violation*** error which could occur because of your dependencies/xml file that are trying to access the memory which is not allowed to.
- To check detailed error logs or to check what causing the issue to debug your code.

  1. Try running with `--debug` or `--verbose` flags.

`func host start --debug`:

[image]

`func host start --Verbose`:

[image]

**References:**

1. [SO- Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72281022/19991670)
2. [Language Worker Process exited. Pid=1652-(devcodef1.com)](https://devcodef1.com/news/1038033/azure-function-blob-trigger-error-language-worker-process-exited)