When debugging with Pycharm, code that should not have been executed was executed
When I was debugging Python code with Pycharm, I encountered a strange problem where a function that should not have been executed was executed. Here is my code：
import os

input_dir = "D:/MyCode/Data/t"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".jpg") and '-' in file:
            if file == "x":
                print("error")

I don't have the file x in my folder, but when I set a breakpoint in the print ("error") code, print ("error") executes and outputs an error. If I set breakpoints at if file. endscan (". jpg") and '-' in file:, print ("error") will not be executed, and when I run the code without debugging, print ("error") will not be executed either. May I ask what caused this?
Location of breakpoint setting

results of execution

This is a reproduced image of my problem. I set a breakpoint at the print function, but the print function that should not have been executed was executed instead, and the program did not exit properly
I tried to change the files in the folder, but even if there were no files in my folder, the print function would still be executed.
Sorry, I may not have explained my question clearly. What I mean is that in my code logic, if file == "x": should never be true, so print("error") should not be executed. However, during breakpoint debugging, when I place a breakpoint at print("error"), the console outputs "error" and the program exits with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005). What could be the reason for this?
I changed the output to file, mask.png is clearly not equal to x, but the console still outputs mask.png.



I'm just curious as well. What if you print something like print("error" + file) ?

Can you log the file names in the for loop?

Are you sure that's the only print('error') in your code? The debugger screenshot doesn't show you hitting the breakpoint, so I think it's coming from something else.

That's the problem with print("error"). If you get an error, your error message should say what's wrong.  It would then be clear that @Barmar is correct: this message has to be from elsewhere.

Please, change the print("error") line to (at least) something like print("error with file: " + file) :)

Also, please note that you should read, in terminal, something like "Process finished with exit code 0" because the print("error") line it's just a print, not an actual exception. From your screenshot it seems there's some actual exception going on. This make us think the problem is not in what you show us :)

@Gigino That will generate an error TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable, it seems that the code before print ('error') has not been executed

@Tom McLean That will generate an error TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable, it seems that the code before print ('error') has not been executed

@Barmar  This is all of my code

The error is caused by the debugger itself erroring out because of a breakpoint being set. The code never runs - the debugger trying to apply the breakpoint is what kills the process (the error code is an access violation, which usually means a bad pointer or null reference in the C-level code). It's not related to the code being run or the breakpoint being hit; it's from the initialization of the debugger when a breakpoint is set (and is why it works when you remove the breakpoint).

@MatsLindh  Thank you very much! The error doesn't occur during runtime, and it should be because of the breakpoint during debugging.

When you use an IDE, the current working directory may not be what you expect. You should add a debug print (print(file) immediately after for file in files:) to make absolutely sure of what actually happens.

@Frank Yellin   Apologies, I may not have explained my question clearly. In the code logic, print("error") should not be executed, but when I place a breakpoint at that line, the console prints "error" (or any other string I replace it with).

@Gigino   I may not have explained my question clearly. In the code logic, print("error") should not be executed, but when I place a breakpoint at that line, the console prints "error".

Change the print statement to print(file, "error") and show us the output.  But right now, you're claiming that something that's impossible is happening.

Yep, it's a bug in the bundled version of the debugger (pydevd iirc) in PyCharm or the integration / state between PyCharm and pydevd. A debugger injects itself in many locations, and thus, it's not the code itself that's the issue. The error (and the line of code being run) is caused by the debugger itself.

@Frank Yellin   I have updated my question.

@iceage Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72281022/446792, and update the question.
